# How to validate empty cells in a DataGridView? (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know please if there is any proper way to validate empty fields inside a DataGridView. I mean, that there are no empty rows inside the grid. (not just fields, the entire row).
Please if anyone has any idea of ​​the event I should use or the code it would be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're probably better off validating the contents of the `DataGridview.DataSource` object. What is your use case for the `DataGridView`?

Comment: I don't use a DataSource. I've created my own columns, so, I need to validate that there isn't empty rows. Does make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. Use the cast method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast)) on the Rows collection to an IEnumerable(Of DataGridViewRow)
2. Use the where method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where)) to iterate over the collection
3. Use the cast method on the Cells collection of the currently iterated row to an IEnumerable(Of DataGridViewCell)
4. Use the all method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all)) to iterate over the collection
5. Use a conditional statement to check where the cell's value is nothing

Example:

```vb
Dim emptyRows = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Where(Function(row) row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).All(Function(cell) cell.Value Is Nothing))
If (emptyRows.Any()) Then
    ' do something with the empty rows
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for answer my question. I'm gonna try doing that you mentioned. Every single thing helps.